# How to generate dynamic select boxes using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, api

I'm going to create a simple E-commerce application. I have  API call, which returns variations object like below. I want to dynamically generate variation boxes. Right now I am receiving one option value, I want to receive options value like image which I have referred to. In addition, the select boxes are dynamic--there can be more than three variations. How can I achieve this result? Thanks in advance.

[image]

```js
var variations = [{
        NameValueList: [
            { Name: "Color", Value: ["Cloud White / Core Black"] },
            { Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)", Value: ["11"] },
        ]
    },
    {
        NameValueList: [
            { Name: "Color", Value: ["Cloud White / Core Green"] },
            { Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)", Value: ["13"] },
        ]
    },
    {
        NameValueList: [
            { Name: "Color", Value: ["Cloud White / Core White"] },
            { Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)", Value: ["15"] },
        ]
    },
]


document.getElementById("generateVariations").addEventListener("click", () => {
    var html;
    variations.map(el => {
        html = el.NameValueList.map(nameValue => {
            return `<select name="${nameValue.Name}">
                     <option value="${nameValue.Value[0]}">${nameValue.Value[0]}</option>
                  </select>`
        })
    })

    document.getElementById("variations2").innerHTML = html.join('')

})
```

```html
<div id="variations2"></div>
<button id="generateVariations">Generate variations</button>
```

Comment: So from the given code sample that you gave, on the variations variable, each object inside the `NameValueList` should have a `select` tag? and are the `Values` property represent the the number of `options`?

Comment: No, in this example my aim is to generate 2 select boxes, first which holds all Color options and the second which holds all Value options

Comment: so if we were to implement your example, you would expect 2 `select boxes` with 3 `options` on each `select boxes` which has all the same values right?

Comment: yes you are right, values would be Color("Cloud White / Core Black", "Cloud White / Core Green", "Cloud White / Core White") and US Shoe Size ("11", "13", "15")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answering my questions, this is the solution that I can propose.

First, we need to reconstruct the array of objects on `variations` using `reduce()` function, so we can loop easily on the next step. We can also use 1 loop for this but it will be messy, so I thought of we need to do it separately for at least it'll make less mess.

So we want to reconstruct it to this:

```json
[
  "Color": ["Cloud White / Core Black", "Cloud White / Core Black", "Cloud White / Core Black"].
  "US Shoe Size (Women's)": ["11", "13", "15"]
]
```

Then now we can loop the newly reconstructed array of objects and convert it to a string using `.join('')` method, and render it on a `div` element.

```js
var variations = [{
        NameValueList: [
            { Name: "Color", Value: ["Cloud White / Core Black"] },
            { Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)", Value: ["11"] },
        ]
    },
    {
        NameValueList: [
            { Name: "Color", Value: ["Cloud White / Core Green"] },
            { Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)", Value: ["13"] },
        ]
    },
    {
        NameValueList: [
            { Name: "Color", Value: ["Cloud White / Core White"] },
            { Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)", Value: ["15"] },
        ]
    },
]


document.getElementById("generateVariations").addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Reconstruct array of object to easier manage rendering of elements
    const new_variations = variations.reduce((a, b) => {
      // If property already exist in variable "a", push values, else, create one
      b.NameValueList.forEach(obj => {
        let found_variant
        // Finds an existing object based on the 'name' property and initialize it on the 'found_variant' variable
        if (found_variant = a.find(e => e.name === obj.Name)) {
          found_variant.options.push(obj.Value[0]);
        } else {
          a.push({ name: obj.Name, options: [obj.Value[0]] });
        }
      })
      
      return a
    }, [])
    // Loop using the new reconstructed array of objects to render
    const html = new_variations.map(obj => (`
      <label>${obj.name}</label>
      <select name="${obj.name}">
        ${obj.options.map(option => `<option value="${option}">${option}</option>`).join('')}
      </select>
    `)).join('')

    document.getElementById("variations2").innerHTML = html

})
```

```html
<div id="variations2"></div>
<button id="generateVariations">Generate variations</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but the structure for storing your data doesn't seem to be optimal. But if it's given (you cannot change it), then that's that :)

```js
var variations = [{
    NameValueList: [{
        Name: "Color",
        Value: ["Cloud White / Core Black"]
      },
      {
        Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)",
        Value: ["11"]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    NameValueList: [{
        Name: "Color",
        Value: ["Cloud White / Core Green"]
      },
      {
        Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)",
        Value: ["13"]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    NameValueList: [{
        Name: "Color",
        Value: ["Cloud White / Core White"]
      },
      {
        Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)",
        Value: ["15"]
      },
    ]
  },
]

const selectObjects = (variations) => {
  return variations.reduce((a, {
    NameValueList: c
  }) => {
    c.forEach(({
      Name,
      Value
    }) => {
      if (typeof a[Name] === "undefined") a[Name] = []
      a[Name] = [...a[Name], ...Value]
    })
    return a
  }, {})
}

const selectHtml = (name, values) => {
  let html = ''
  html += `<label>${name}<select id="${name}">`
  values.forEach(value => {
    html += `<option>${ value }</option>`
  })
  html += '</select></label>'
  return html
}

const selectsHtml = (selectObjects) => {
  html = ''
  for (let key in selectObjects) {
    html += selectHtml(key, selectObjects[key])
  }
  return html
}

const container = document.getElementById('container')

container.innerHTML = selectsHtml(selectObjects(variations))
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```